# Is there a way to create Datatables from a gridview in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I am wanting to create a datatable from a gridview in asp.net. This is what I have so far. I want to use the jquery datatables plugin to create a table that can be filtered and sorted. Is there a way to do this from a gridview, using an sql datasource or is there something else that i need to do, like create an html. The only problem is that i need to be able to have the table update or be dynamic.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Glossary.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home.Glossary" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title spellcheck="true">Glossary</title>
    <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView2" runat="server"></asp:LoginView>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div style="margin-left: 720px">

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F6F3" BorderColor="#E6E2D8" BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333">
                    <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
                    <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
                    <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:Login>
            </AnonymousTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>

    </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TedGlossary" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Glsry_Taylor %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TermText], [DefNbr], [DefVerNbr], [DefText], [AmplifyingExplanationText], [SeeAlsoText], [AuthoritativeSrcText], [ScopeName], [DomnName], [GovernanceStateName], [LastUpdtTimestamp] FROM [Glossary] ORDER BY [TermText]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"

            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#example').dataTable();
                  } );

             DataKeyNames="TermText,DefNbr,DefVerNbr" DataSourceID="TedGlossary" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True">

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TermText" HeaderText="Term" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TermText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DefNbr" HeaderText="Definition #" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DefNbr" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DefVerNbr" HeaderText="Definition Vers #" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DefVerNbr" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DefText" HeaderText="Definition" SortExpression="DefText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AmplifyingExplanationText" HeaderText="Amplifying Explanation" SortExpression="AmplifyingExplanationText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SeeAlsoText" HeaderText="See Also" SortExpression="SeeAlsoText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AuthoritativeSrcText" HeaderText="Authoritative Source" SortExpression="AuthoritativeSrcText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ScopeName" HeaderText="Scope Name" SortExpression="ScopeName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DomnName" HeaderText="Domn Name" SortExpression="DomnName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GovernanceStateName" HeaderText="Governance State" SortExpression="GovernanceStateName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastUpdtTimestamp" HeaderText="Last Update" SortExpression="LastUpdtTimestamp" />
            </Columns>

           <script src="DataTables-1.9.4/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="DataTables-1.9.4/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

        </asp:GridView>




    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the elements of your page in the right place first, you're attempting to link Javascript files and call jQuery functions in the middle of your body, this needs to be done in the head section:

```
<head>
    <script src="DataTables-1.9.4/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="DataTables-1.9.4/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#GridView1').dataTable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Notice also, that you must use the ID of your GridView to initialize the DataTable.  Searching will be enabled automatically, to enable filtering, you'll have to use TemplateFields in place of your BoundFields, see http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/222381-insert-data-using-gridview-footerrow/ for an example of how to convert them.  Finally, in your Code Behind, you need to force the GridView to generate proper `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, and `<tfoot>` sections:

```
    gvPortfolio.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
    gvPortfolio.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    gvPortfolio.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
```

Just add `<FooterStyle CssClass="FilterCell" />` (or some such thing) to add a class to each footer cell, then use that class to connect your filtering:

```
$("tbody td.FilterCell").each(function (i) {
    this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect(oTable.fnGetColumnData(i));
    $('select', this).change(function () {
        oTable.fnFilter($(this).val(), i);
    });
});
```

You can find the rest of this example at http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html.  Note, as shown above, you're looking for the `<td>` elements generated by the GridView, rather than the `<th>` elements expected by the example.